# AttributeError: 'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'dt'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have a `df`:

```
    id  timestamp                       data  group Date
27001   27242   2020-01-01 09:07:21.277 19.5    1   2020-01-01
27002   27243   2020-01-01 09:07:21.377 19.0    1   2020-01-01
27581   27822   2020-01-02 07:53:05.173 19.5    1   2020-01-02
27582   27823   2020-01-02 07:53:05.273 20.0    1   2020-01-02
27647   27888   2020-01-02 10:01:46.380 20.5    1   2020-01-02
...
```

and I would like to calculate the time difference between row 1 and row 2 in seconds. I could do it with

```
df['timediff'] = (df['timestamp'].shift(-1) - df['timestamp']).dt.total_seconds()
```

However, when I zoom in to look at only 2 rows, ie. row1 and row0, with code:

```
difference = (df.loc[0, 'timestamp'] - df.loc[1, 'timestamp']).dt.total_seconds()
```

it returned error

> AttributeError: 'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'dt'

Why is this happening?

Comment: In the first what kind of object has a `.dt` attribute?  a dataframe?

Comment: @hpaulj Oh it's only for series, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @hpaulj said in the comments, `dt` is only associated with `dataframe` like object.

So to obtain `total seconds` you have to use `difference = (df.loc[0, 'timestamp'] - df.loc[1, 'timestamp']).total_seconds()`

Answer (score 5):

By inspection the following is a [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html):

```
type(df['timestamp'].shift(-1) - df['timestamp'])
```

Series has an accessor (*dt*) object for datetime like properties. However, the following is a [TimeDelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) with no dt accessor:

```
type(df.loc[0, 'timestamp'] - df.loc[1, 'timestamp'])
```

Just call the following (without the *dt* accessor) to solve the error:

```
difference = (df.loc[0, 'timestamp'] - df.loc[1, 'timestamp']).total_seconds()
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I didn't know it was an accessor (dt) object. Do you know what resources I could use to teach myself?

Comment: @nilsinelabore you can start here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/index.htm and here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/index.htm

Answer (score 4):

In case you end up here and want to extract days:
`(df.loc[0, 'timestamp'] - df.loc[1, 'timestamp']).days`

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'timestamp': ['2023-11-19 12:00:00', '2023-11-19 12:01:00', '2023-11-19 12:02:00', '2023-11-19 12:04:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

# Calculate time difference in seconds 
df['time_diff_seconds'] = df['timestamp'].diff().dt.total_seconds().fillna(0)

"""print(df)
            timestamp  time_diff_seconds
0 2023-11-19 12:00:00                0.0
1 2023-11-19 12:01:00               60.0
2 2023-11-19 12:02:00               60.0
3 2023-11-19 12:04:00              120.0"""


df['time_diff_seconds1'] = (df['timestamp'].shift(-1) - df['timestamp']).dt.total_seconds()
"""print(df)
           timestamp  time_diff_seconds  time_diff_seconds1
0 2023-11-19 12:00:00                0.0                60.0
1 2023-11-19 12:01:00               60.0                60.0
2 2023-11-19 12:02:00               60.0               120.0
3 2023-11-19 12:04:00              120.0                 NaN
"""
```